# Need to write a mySQL query in php script which will change automatically with the change in user input in every submit session

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, checkbox

I have a mySQL database which looks like this :

[image]

I have a checkbox type form with a submit button as follows in html.

> a [ ]   b [ ]   c [ ]   [Submit]

User can select any of these options and press Submit.

Based on this,

**I need to write a mysql query in my php script which will change with the change in user input in every submit session.**

eg1.

User selects,

> a [x]   b [ ]   c [x]   **[Submit]**

according to my php script,

```
$a=1
$b=0
$c=1
```

now my query should automatically read above values and become something like :

```
select name from table1 where a=$a AND c=$c;
```

which should give me results :

```
x1
x2
```

eg2.

User selects,

> a [x]   b [x]   c []   **[Submit]**

according to my php script,

```
$a=1
$b=1
$c=0
```

now my query should automatically read above values and become something like :

```
select name from table1 where a=$a AND b=$b;
```

which should give me results :

```
x2
x4
```

Basically whichever checkbox remains unchecked, we have to ignore it in the query.

Comment: I actually tried a lot of different combinations of AND - ORs. Changed the 0s in the table to -1 so that my user input value is either 0 or 1 which i thought i could use to query but i can't seem to get anywhere. I know this is what i have to do, But can't figure out the syntax to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you are trying to query specific columns, which your checkboxes represent. If you compact those values into an array you can iterate over them and remove any with zero values like this:

```
<?php
$a=1;
$b=0;
$c=1;

$array = compact("a", "b", "c"); // convert vars into an array
$wherePart = '';

foreach ( $array AS $key => $value ) {
    if ( $value ) {
        $wherePart .= "$key = $" . $key . ' AND '; // build var with items containing values
    }
}

$query = "select name from table1 where " . rtrim($wherePart, ' AND ');

// select name from table1 where a = $a AND c = $c
```

This can be refactored but it should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

here is a working example

```
<?
if (isset ($_POST['submit']) ): 
    $Where = "";
    extract($_POST);

    if (!empty($a) || !empty($b) || !empty ($c)) 
        $Where = "where ";


        if (! empty($a)) 
            $Where .= "a = $a ";

        if (! empty($a) && ! empty($b)) 
            $Where .= 'and ';

        if (! empty($b)) 
            $Where .= "b = $b ";

        if (! empty($b) && ! empty($c)) 
            $Where .= 'and ';

        if (! empty($c)) 
            $Where .= "c = $c";

echo $Where;        
    endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select name from table1 where a like '%$a%' AND b like '%$b%' AND c like '%$c%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked. Quite similar to what Ahmad suggested.

```
if($a == 1)
     $str1 = "a=1 and ";
else $str1 = "";

if($b == 1)
     $str2 = "b=1 and ";
else $str2 = "";

if($c == 1)
      $str3 = "c=1 and ";
else $str3 = "";

$sqlstd="select name from table1 where ";

$sqltmp=$sqlstd.$str1.$str2.$str3;

$sql=chop($sqltmp,"and ");

echo $sql;
```

and then use $sql further to output the query result.
This is more hardcoded but i guess its okay in this case since i know that my table only has 0 or 1 value and the checkbox tick will result in either 1 or 0.